# Create multi entities in Symfony4 Unit tests

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, testing

Since few days, I'm trying to learn Symfony Unit Test.
I made my first test but I noticed one thing :
For my first test, I tested a simple implode for some tags :

```
class TagsTransformerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testTransform()
  {
      $tagsArray = [
        $this->createTag('Symfony'),
        $this->createTag('Test'),
        $this->createTag('Unit'),
      ];

      $transformer = $this->getMockedTransformer();
      $tagsTransformed = $transformer->transform($tagsArray);

      $this->assertEquals('Symfony, Test, Unit', $tagsTransformed);
  }

  private function getMockedTransformer()
  {
      $entityManager = $this
          ->getMockBuilder(ObjectManager::class)
          ->disableOriginalConstructor()
          ->getMock();

      return new TagsTransformer($entityManager);
  }

  private function createTag($name)
  {
     $tag = new Tag();
     $tag->setName($name);

     return $tag;
  }

}
```

As you can see, I have to create a createTag() method to build some tags, but I wonder if I can like Laravel :

```
$anakin = factory(User::class)->states('anakin')->create();
$post = factory(Post::class)->create(['author_id' => $anakin->id]);
factory(Post::class, 2)->create();
factory(Comment::class, 3)->create(['post_id' => $post->id]);
```

My question is, is there any way to use a object like factory in Symfony to avoid going through an alternative method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better:

```
$tagsTransformed = ($this->getMockedTransformer())->transform($tagsArray);
$this->assertEquals('Symfony, Test, Unit', $tagsTransformed);
```

Yes i think you can, [check this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/unit_testing.html#the-basics)

```
$form = $this->factory->create(TestedType::class);
```

Comment: In my case, I dont want to test a FormValidation but just build an ArrayCollection, here factory->create() expected a class which implement FormTypeInterface